# Website Displays Error When Accessed

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql

Suddenly I'm getting error on my front page and backend pages
[image][image]

Comment: Rajiv it seems like the table not exist in the database. please check the same and create the table and columns accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your site compilation is on So follow below solution

**Solution 1:**

Turn Off the compiler from your terminal steps

1. Open your terminal /connect your ssh access
2. Go to your magento root via this command `cd \yourpathtomagentoDir`
3. Fire this commnad  `php -f compiler.php disable`
4. After this do compile `php -f compiler.php compile`
5. After this enable compile `php -f compiler.php enable`

**Solution 2:**

1. Go to your module's xml file located in `app/etc/modules` and disable the module
2. Clear the cache
3. Now you are able to login in back end
4. Disable the compiler and install your module
5. Go compile and enable your magento compile

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed any custom extension regarding wishlist?

Meanwhile please try below process:

1. Reïndex all indexes: php ./shell/indexer.php -reindexall
2. Delete cache: rm -rf var/cache/* or Rename the cache folder under var to Cache_backup.

   It may occur because wishlist_item table is not present in DB. If you have backup of your DB please try to add that table.